# How to update windows SDK on `windows-latest` on Github Action

Tags: windows, github-actions

On a local Win-10 VM, my build succeed but not on GitHub actions (https://github.com/dilawar/Smoldyn/runs/2636566648?check_suite_focus=true). The only difference b/w GitHub action and my local machine is the Windows SDK version: on my local machine it is `10.0.18336.0` while on Github it is `10.0.17763`.

I am getting the following error at Github Action

```
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5572172Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\wtypes.h(745): message : in expansion of macro '_VARIANT_BOOL' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5771590Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(487,17): error C2059: syntax error: '/' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5775983Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(502,17): warning C5103: pasting '/' and '/' does not result in a valid preprocessing token [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5781668Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared\wtypes.h(745): message : in expansion of macro '_VARIANT_BOOL' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5784135Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(502,17): error C2059: syntax error: '/' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5786253Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(530,17): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5787985Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(531,13): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5789635Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(533,9): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5791292Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(534,5): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5793201Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(665,16): error C2079: 'varDefaultValue' uses undefined struct 'tagVARIANT' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.5795324Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\oaidl.h(950,16): error C2079: 'varValue' uses undefined struct 'tagVARIANT' [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
2021-05-21T05:54:42.6072200Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\propidlbase.h(319,24): warning C5103: pasting '/' and '/' does not result in a valid preprocessing token [D:\a\Smoldyn\Smoldyn\build\source\libSteve\Steve.vcxproj]
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/15035#issuecomment-742427969 suggests updating the SDK version which goes well with my experience.

How to update windows SDK on github actions on `windows-latest`?

Comment: There is [this action](https://github.com/fbactions/setup-winsdk) that might help. Did you try it?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks. It installs the SDK. Now I need to figure out how to force cmake to use the new SDK.

Comment: Did you try setting CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION to 10.x ? For example using something like `set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.X)` or equivalent in shell in your workflow? (e.g: `cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.X`)

Comment: https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules/blob/main/FindWindowsSDK.cmake is very helpful. I think I am quite close to a solution.

Comment: Let me know once you find it! :D

Comment: Still struggling and calling it a day. Will try again later. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION.html#variable:CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION looked promising but alas dindn't help for cmake to pick the right SDK version. I don't want to hardcode the paths in cmake.

Comment: @GuiFalourd The solution turned out to be simple. As you suggested `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` did the trick after using the action you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ssandrews/Smoldyn/pull/72/files#diff-5ce5c9ff86f58b1f87b35b5227b2e84cb69f022d6741e1854f3e1e181091773c shows the changes I made to fix this.

In short, passing `-D-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0.19041.0` fixed the issue. Before that, I had to enable [this action](https://github.com/fbactions/setup-winsdk) as suggested by @GuiFalourd in the comment above.